# Altering vs adding column - setting all dates in month to one end date

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to add rank by sales and also change the date column to a 'month end' field that would have one month end date per month - if that makes sense?
Would you alter table and add column or could you just rename the date field and use set and case to make all March dates = 3-31-18 and all April 4-30-18? 
I got this far:

```
       UPDATE table1
        SET DATE=EOMONTH(DATE) AS MONTH_END;       
        ALTER TABLE table1
        ADD COLUMN RANK INT AFTER sales;
        UPDATE table1
        SET RANK=
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cust ORDER BY sales DESC);
        LIMIT 2
```

can i do two sets in a row like that without adding an update?  I'm looking for top 2 within each month -  would this work?  I feel like this is right and most efficient query, but its not working - any help appreciated!!

orig table

```
+------+----------+-------+--+
| CUST |   DATE   | SALES |  |
+------+----------+-------+--+
|   36 | 3-5-2018 |    50 |  |
|   37 | 3-15-18  |   100 |  |
|   38 | 3-25-18  |    65 |  |
|   37 | 4-5-18   |    95 |  |
|   39 | 4-21-18  |   500 |  |
|   40 | 4-45-18  |   199 |  |
+------+----------+-------+--+
```

desired output

```
+------+-----------+-------+------+
| CUST | Month End | SALES | Rank |
+------+-----------+-------+------+
|      |           |       |      |
|   37 | 3-31-18   |   100 |    1 |
|   38 | 3-31-18   |    65 |    2 |
|   39 | 4-30-18   |   500 |    1 |
|   40 | 4-30-18   |   199 |    2 |
+------+-----------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Do you want rank to be added in the table along with month end column? or rank is just on select list along with aggregated data? Also, in you expected output why 50 and 95 are not there?Do you just want the top 2 for a month?

Comment: yes looking for rank and month end to both be in final table - and the other date column either removed or altered to reflect Month End column. And yes also to rank wanting to show only top 2

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected output I think this may work as well.

```
create table Salesdate (Cust int, Dates date, Sales int) 

insert into Salesdate values 

(36 , '2018-03-05' ,    50  ) 
,(37 , '2018-03-15'  ,   100 ) 
,(38 , '2018-03-25'  ,   65  ) 
,(37 , '2018-04-05'   ,  95  ) 
,(40 , '2018-04-25'  ,   199 ) 
,(39 , '2018-04-21'  ,   500 )
```

Updating the same column dates to the last day of the month (EOmonth will help to give last day of the month), you can add a separate column or update the column as you prefer.

```
Update Salesdate 
set Dates = eomonth(Dates)
```

Add a column called rank in the table.

```
Alter table Salesdate 
add rank int
```

Update the column rank which was just added.

```
update Salesdate 
set Salesdate.[rank] =  tbl.Ranked from  
(select   Cust, Sales,  Dates ,  rank() over (Partition by Dates order by Sales Desc) 
Ranked from Salesdate ) tbl
where tbl.Cust = salesdate.Cust 
and tbl.Sales = salesdate.Sales 
and tbl.dates = salesdate.Dates
```

--Not sure if this step is necessary if you want your final table to have only rank 1 and 2, then you can delete the data. Or it can be filtered out only on select list as well. Please note that sometimes rank may skip the number if we don't have unique set of sales amount for a given customer.

```
;With cte as ( 
select * from Salesdate) 

delete from cte
where [RANK] > 2  

select * from Salesdate 
order by dates, [RANK]
```

Output

```
Cust    Dates   Sales   rank
37  2018-03-31  100      1
38  2018-03-31  65       2
39  2018-04-30  500      1
40  2018-04-30  199      2
```

Comment: to make it more efficient, could you just alter the table to add column and then update to set new date column and rank?  I updated my query above in the orig question. Would that syntax work? Thanks.

Comment: @josh_00 I don't think your update will work, have you tried running it? I don't think you can use window function directly in your update, and not sure why you are using group by

Comment: i think it's the last step im struggling with - I have update, alter and then another update for the  date and rank columns.  Now i just need to see the top two per month.  I thought limit two or select*top within each month would work but not sure how that looks

Comment: i guess that's assuming i did the rank update correctly

Comment: @josh_00 Did you get a chance to run the query which I posted ? I think it gives your expected output.

Comment: it didn't work for me but I guess I'm confused by the multiple tables created? couldn't I do this without creating any tables?  after the alter salesdate add rank - i don't follow the rest.  I feel like after that point I just have to define rank column and cherry pick top 2 per mo